# How do I use the ionic infinite scroll in conjunction with SQL lite data capacitor 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using SQL lite to store data in my Android app, and I'd like to use infinite scroll to improve performance.

I read the documentation.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll

This is my **database.service.ts** file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IRoute } from '../models/IRoute';
import { QueryService } from './query.service';
import { SQLiteDBConnection, DBSQLiteValues } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {

  constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {

  }

  async getAllFavoriteRoutes(limit: number, offset: number): Promise<IRoute[]> {
    return this.queryService.executeQuery<any>(async (db: SQLiteDBConnection) => {
      var routes: DBSQLiteValues = await db.query("SELECT * FROM favoriteroutes LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", [limit, offset]);
      return routes.values as IRoute[];
    });
  }

}
```

Then I my **favorites.page.ts** I use this method like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseService } from '../services/database.service';
import { IRoute } from '../models/IRoute';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-favorites',
  templateUrl: './favorites.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorites.page.scss'],
})
export class FavoritesPage implements OnInit {

  public favoriteroutes: IRoute[] = [];
  limit: number = 10;
  offset: number = 0;

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.loadData(null);
  }

  loadData(event) {
    this.databaseService.getAllFavoriteRoutes(this.limit, this.offset).then((data) => {
      this.favoriteroutes = this.favoriteroutes.concat(data);
      this.offset += this.limit;
      if (event) {
        event.target.complete();
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      if (event) {
        event.target.complete();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

And this is my **favorites.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="app-theme-color">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Favorites</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content color="secondary">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-card class="animate__animated animate__slideInLeft" *ngFor="let route of favoriteroutes"
          [routerLink]="['/', 'routedetails', route.id]">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <div class="ion-text-begin">
                {{ route.nameroute }}
              </div>
            </ion-col>             
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

The issue is that the Android app only displays 10 records and does not scroll or show the other data loading.

I tried several tutorials before this one, but it was based on an API request.

Is it possible to use infinitescroll with SQL lite data?

Comment: A couple things spring to mind: 1. `@Input()` is missing on the `FavoritesPage.favoriteroutes`. 2. I've had issues in the past with infinite scroll not triggering if there aren't enough items to fill the screen (i.e. nothing to scroll)(EDIT: on first load). It sounds like you have enough items though, so I would think #1. When it updates, the view has no way of knowing the binding has changed.

Comment: I have like 50+ records in the database hardcode to test is. Do I have to place @input for the variable favorites routes?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs - `@Input` (capitalized!) decorator is needed when your data changes and you need a UI view to update. In your example, `limit` and `offset` are NOT bound directly to the UI so they don't need it. But `favoriteroutes` (which should be `favoriteRoutes` camelCased) is: `*ngFor="let route of favoriteroutes"`. Without `@Input()` decorator the UI will never update when the property is changed because it can't _see_ that it's changed. (This is what "binding" is all about)

Comment: As for the 50 records, it's not what is in the database (for my problem). I had a problem because the first set of results (defined by your `limit` property) was sometimes not enough to create a scrollbar in the window. So there was nothing to "scroll" and so the `loadData` event never could fire. I ended up setting a timer to manually trigger the `loadData` event just in case. (Was a bit of a hack though).

Comment: BTW `@Input` documentation is at https://angular.io/api/core/Input . The other link I didn't realize is specifically for nesting components which doesn't sound like it is relavent to you.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hello @wraiford, your anwser about the items was the clue. I increase the limit variable to  50 and the infinite scrolls works. Thank you!